# Could we directly copy image to MediaWiki images folder?

Tags: mediawiki

I am running a local host web-server for MediaWiki (XAMPP).

Typically, an upload special page is used to upload images. These images are stored in the WIKI_HOME/images folder and some records are inserted in the database.

I use this wiki on a local machine and for myself only. I need the speed so I tried to copy an image to WIKI_HOME/images instead of uploading it using the upload extensions. But it does not show up in the wiki. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: It would be useful to know what your requirements really are. "Speed"? How comes isn't Special:Upload speedy for you, upload to localhost should be instant. Do you mean speed of some step other than the file transfer itself and if yes which?

Comment: @Nemo ```upload to localhost should be instant``` is your opinion.

Comment: No, it's not an opinion. https://serverfault.com/questions/234223/how-fast-is-127-0-0-1 https://superuser.com/questions/857549/localhost-tcp-throughput-performance-differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bulk upload images from the local server using the [UploadLocal extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUploadLocal) or the [importImages.php script](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aImportImages.php). You could set up importImages.php to run on a regular basis to import any images in a specific folder.